# Components of tridimensional vector in flat four dimensional space

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory

I'm (almost self-)studying group theory trying to understand what "quantum field theory" really means. I have some confusions regarding the group theory, because it is a really wide topic given in my course "as it is", without proofs and nothing, so I'm trying to understand at least the most basic things by myself.

This said, I go to my problem. I don't understand well the topic, so maybe my next phrase is incorrect, but what I understood in all of this is that a vector is a vector just with respect to the invariance with a group.

So here comes the problem, because what to do with an $\text{SO}(3)$ vector (*it's maybe incorrect to say "$\text{SO}(3)$ vector", but this comes from my incomprehension of the topic*) in a four-dimensional space? I understand that its $0$-indexed component is not defined, but what if I invent that its zero component is $0$? It would also be an $\text{SO}(1,3)$ vector?

Specifically I'm talking of the *tridimensional* electromagnetic field ($\text{SO}(3)$ vector field?) generated by a four-potential $\text{SO}(1,3)$ vector field. So for example, I read in "D'Auria, Trigiante - From Special Relativity to Feynman Diagrams" that $\boldsymbol{E}$ vector is a tridimensional vector and so the "covariant" and "contravariant" components are the same $E_i=E^i$, and it is not even necessary to strictly follow the Einstein convention because in this case I can rise and lower indices as I want; but in my professor notes I read $E^i=-E_i$ (I suppose because $g^{ij}=-\delta^{ij}$ for $i,j=1,2,3$), so I'm really not understanding what's going on.

Same problem when I expand in Fourier series the four-potential and appears the tridimensional wave vector $\boldsymbol{k}$

It's weeks I'm thinking about this, but I don't find a way out, so thanks to anyone that can and will help!

Edit:

To be clearer in  my problem, consider the Fourier series expansion of the four-potential and the condition imposed by Lorentz gauge $\partial_\alpha A^\alpha=0$, both exposed in the following
\begin{gather*}
A_\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{r})
=
\sum\limits_{\boldsymbol{n}\in\mathbb{Z}^3}
%\widehat{A}_\alpha
a_\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{k})
e^{i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}}
\\
\sum\limits_{\boldsymbol{n}\in\mathbb{Z}^3} 
g^{\alpha\beta}
\left(
\partial_\beta a_\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{k})
+i a_\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{k})\delta^j_\beta k_j
\right)
e^{-i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}}
=
0
\end{gather*}
Consider that $\boldsymbol{k}$ is a tridimensional vector and so its $0$-th component is not defined, or alternatively I can define a $k_0=0$ so I can coherently write $k_\beta$ (it's not the four-vector wave vector obviously and maybe it's not a four-vector at all!).
So what I have to do now with $g^{\alpha\beta}\delta^j_\beta k_j$? Is it equal to $k^\alpha$ (as if it was a four vector) or is it equal to $-k^\alpha$ (as if it was not a four vector, because actually I have a tridimensional vector in my hands)...

This has really serious implications, especially when I arrive to define the spin, because from the known equation $a_\alpha(t,\boldsymbol{k})=
\epsilon_\alpha^+(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{-i\omega_k t} +\epsilon_\alpha^-(\boldsymbol{k}) e^{i\omega_k t}$ I obtain the following result
\begin{gather*}
 \begin{cases}
  \epsilon_0^+(\boldsymbol{k}) 
  =
  -\frac{k^j}{|\boldsymbol{k}|}
  \epsilon_j^+(\boldsymbol{k}) 
  \\
  \epsilon_0^-(\boldsymbol{k})
  =
  \frac{k^j}{|\boldsymbol{k}|}
  \epsilon_j^-(\boldsymbol{k})
  \end{cases}
\end{gather*}
So its like one polarization vector is perpendicolar to the (actual) four-vector of the wave, but the other it's not!

I understand there are a lot of arguments in this question, but they are all related by the same topic, and it is the behaviour of tridimensional vector in a fourdimensional spacetime. They are just different "manifestations" of the same question, that can inspire some useful answers in one of the several topics.

Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: Honestly this is a lot for anyone to teach on the subject, and you are definitely mixing up many things here incorrectly. At this point I would recommend a pure course in group theory as you should first understand what a group is.

Comment: Ok, maybe I was a bit confusing. Onestly I got no time for a complete course in group theory (I'm very slow in learning, so I would never get near to  degree this way), but here I just wanted to explicate the several situations in which I encounted this problem. I know something about groups anyway, I'm not completely dry on the argument: I'm just asking how a tridimensional vector in euclidean metric, behave respect to a fourdimensional minkowskian space, just this.